# VBA to rearch email ID in another excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple VBA code with search email ID in another excel sheet and provide cell address. I am getting error that

> "Object variable or With block variable not set".

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = ws0.Range("AA2:AA1048576").Find(email0, LookAt:=xlWhole)
MsgBox cell.Address
```

Updated code (from a comment below):

```
Dim myFileNameDir0 As String
Dim ws0 As Worksheet
Dim cell0 As Range
Dim email0 As String

email0 = ws4.Range("D" & 2)
myFileNameDir0 = TextBox1.Value
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir0, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws0 = Worksheets(1)
ws0.Activate

Dim cell As Range
Set cell = ws0.Range("AA2:AA1048576").Find(email0, LookAt:=xlWhole)
MsgBox cell.Address
```

Any help welcome.

Comment: I am guessing that you are getting the error on the line starting with `Set`. If that's the case then the problem resides probably within `ws0`. From your code it is not clear if `ws0` is the first worksheet in the Excel file you just opened or if `ws0` should be the first worksheet in the Excel file with the macro. In other words, is it `Set ws0 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` or should it be `Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open ....` and then `Set ws0 = wbNew.Worksheets(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem might be in the worksheet identifier.
What happens if you change it to read;

```
Set cell =  sheets("NAME").Range("AA2:AA1048576").Find(email0, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Also, what is email0? Is it a variable or a string?
What have you dimmed email0 to be as, if it is a variable?

Comment: email0 is a string.

Comment: complete code
Dim myFileNameDir0 As String
Dim ws0 As Worksheet
Dim cell0 As Range
Dim email0 As String

email0 = ws4.Range("D" & 2)

myFileNameDir0 = TextBox1.Value
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir0, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws0 = Worksheets(1)
ws0.Activate

Dim cell As Range
Set cell = ws0.Range("AA2:AA1048576").Find(email0, LookAt:=xlWhole)
MsgBox cell.Address

Comment: To start with;   - ws4 has not been dimmed or set   -"Dim cell As Range" may be throwing out an error, should be "cell0".   Perhaps this task would be more easily achieved by using a "Match" formula?

Comment: @ZaidShaikh Please don't post code in comments but rather update your original post if you want to add / change something. To show you what I mean I updated the post for you.

Comment: @JohnPhillips Maybe `ws4` is not a variable but merely the [CodeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) as shown here: http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s112/microsoft-excel-vba-worksheet-sheet-name-codename.htm Yet, you are right and such information should be included in the original post (for clarification).